# Python: simple GET request timing out

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have a seemingly simple problem, trying to get the following JSON response from this URL:

> https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/etf

with the following code, but it runs forever (25 min) and seems to timeout, does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/etf')

j = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame([[d['v'] for d in x['c']] for x in j['rows']],
                  columns=[d['label'] for d in j['cols']])
```

Answer (score 0):

That api seems to require User Agent.

```py
import requests

UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': UA
}

r = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/etf', headers=HEADERS)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: hmm, did this work for you? I have the same issue still sadly

Comment: yes, it works for me.  Is there any proxy or something in your environment?

Comment: I'm running it in Google Colab

Comment: maybe nasdaq api rejects requests from Google Colab.  So you should run script on your machine.

Comment: same issue, somehow I can't read the json